# GIF ImageIcon keeps flickering in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, gif, animated-gif

I have to do a little Game in Java Swing for school. I created some gifs for it and wanted to put them in and I did, but the problem is that the gifs flicker sometimes. I really can't find anything on the Internet and honestly I don't even know where to start to look exactly.

My code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class Chicken extends JFrame {

    private int canvasWidth = 560;
    private int canvasHeight = 480;

    private Color sideGreen = new Color(14, 37, 14);
    private Color gapGreen = new Color(56, 148, 56);
    private Color edgeGreen = new Color(49, 129, 49);

    private Image chicken;
    private Image cookie;

    private DrawCanvas canvas;

    public Chicken() {
        canvas = new DrawCanvas();

        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(canvasWidth, canvasHeight));

        try {
            addImages();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.add(canvas);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Chicken");
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class DrawCanvas extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public void update(Graphics g) {
            paintComponent(g);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            setDoubleBuffered(true);
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            g2.setColor(sideGreen);
            g2.fillRect(0, 0, 80, canvasHeight);
            g2.fillRect(canvasWidth - 80, 0, 80, 480);
            g2.setColor(gapGreen);
            g2.fillRect(80, 0, 400, 100);
            g2.fillRect(80, canvasHeight - 100, 400, 100);
            g2.setColor(edgeGreen);
            g2.fillRect(80, 80, 400, 20);
            g2.fillRect(80, canvasHeight - 100, 400, 20);
            g2.drawImage(cookie, 85, 5, this);
            g2.drawImage(chicken, 150, 120, this);
        }
    }

    private void addImages() throws Exception {
        ImageIcon iconCookie = new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PcWC.gif"));
        Image cookieimage = iconCookie.getImage();
        Image newimg = cookieimage.getScaledInstance(70, 70, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        iconCookie = new ImageIcon(newimg);

        ImageIcon iconChicken = new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJA7G.gif"));
        Image chickenimage = iconChicken.getImage();
        Image newimgc = chickenimage.getScaledInstance(250, 250, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        iconChicken = new ImageIcon(newimgc);

        chicken = iconChicken.getImage();
        cookie = iconCookie.getImage();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Chicken());
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong in the code? Or is there another way to do it and I've just done it wrong? The gifs should be fine, I've created them myself and they look fine when I view them from my PC.

[Chicken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJA7G.gif)

[image]

[Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PcWC.gif)

[image]

### Edit

Found out that the chicken isn't flickering when I remove the cookie, but I don't know why.

Comment: `@Override
    public void update(Graphics g)` ***Why*** is the code overriding that method?

Comment: I edited the code in the question to be a [mcve]. (This mostly involves hot-linking to the images.) Does the edited code show the same problem at your end? If not, please go into the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50505425/revisions) & roll back the changes I made.

Comment: *"I've created them myself.."* That being the case.. `Image newimgc = chickenimage.getScaledInstance(250, 250, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);` the best time to scale the images is ***before*** they are loaded by the application!

Comment: Hello @AndrewThompson ! `@Override public void update(Graphics g)` Honestly I'm not too sure, we were taught to do this at school like that. Is there another way? Or should i remove the `@Override`? 
I've tried your changes but it sadly doesn't seem to make a difference. Still flickering. 
I think I'll just change the cookie.gif to a .png that seems to work with the flickering. Thank you so much for the answers though!

Comment: *"Or should i remove the `@Override`?"* Remove the entire method. There is no good to be achieved by changing the existing functionality. When I removed it, I could not see any further flickering in the chicken image. There are other changes I'd also recommend in that code, but it worked without those.

Comment: @AndrewThompson just removed it and tried again but it still flickers after some minutes. I don't know why it doesn't do it with your code, maybe i still have something wrong but i tried to follow everything you suggested. But i think I'll just stick to .png for the logos and .gif for the chicken, looks better the more i look at it too. But thank you soo much for taking your time and helping me i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `setDoubleBuffered(true);` from `paintComponent`. Probably temptative code. You could call it in the constructor, but by default double buffering is on. Move `setBackground(Color.BLACK);` to the constructor.

Then remove the `update` method.

<strike>You normally do not need to call</strike> `super.paintComponent();`. Comment it out, and try to see a change.

You might do `setContentPane(canvas)`.

Should there still be a problem, then it is due to the inner workings of gif handling.

Comment: *"You normally do not need to call `super.paintComponent();`."* It's best practice though.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the response! I've tried it all. When i remove the `super.paintComponent();` it has a weird effect where you can see the previous frames in the background. Also sadly it didn't solve the flickering but thank yu anyways!

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes, it takes care of the correct Graphics switches. For the flickering I wanted to eliminate that being the cause.

Comment: @ArvyMinsk my hope was for the update reimplementation. As your evaluation points to the second gif causing the flickering, Maybe you should try a **JLayeredPane** and/or **OverlayLayout**, so there are two paintComponents on two double buffered backgrounds. Sigh.

Comment: `You normally do not need to call super.paintComponent();.` - you should always invoke super.paintComponent() to make sure the background is cleared before doing any custom painting, otherwise you can have painting artifacts.

Comment: @camickr you are in concert with Andrew Thompson; now a nice strike through.